# one global state for whole app in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Is it good practice to keep all your `state`s in `App.js`?

I.e I have in `App.js`:

```
<div>
  <Navbar/>
  {this.props.children}
  <Footer/>
 </div>
```

And in `<Navbar/>` i have `submenu` that should change a `state` (of a page which `submenu item` redirects to) when clicked on an item in it. The page where the `submenu item` redirects to has its own `state` declared, but I don't know how could i get back up to `App.js` where `Navbar` component is to get state from clicked `submenu item` and pass it back to page where it redirects to.

Comment: that's basically what redux is. It just passes down from the top level `Provider` by context then decides if it should fire re-renders.

Comment: i see, cheers for answer

Comment: you can keep some state local and some state global(in redux). it matter of choice.  thumb rule - if the state does not depend on any other component state use local otherwise global.